# How to bind jQuery .css() function when click menu？

Tags: jquery

I have those following code:

html part：

```
<div id="primary"></div>
```

js part：

```
$(function() {
var menu_contents = 
[ 
    {title: "AA", href: "a.html", submenu:
        [
            {title: "BB", href: "b.html", id: "bb"},
            {title: "CC", href: "c.html", id: "cc"},
            {title: "DD", href: "d.html", id: "dd"}
        ]
    },
    {title: "EE", href: "e.html", id: "ee"},
];

html = $('<div id="secondary">').append($('<div class="block">')
                                .append('<h1 id="h1"  style="color:#ffffff;">Settings</h1>')
                                .append($('<div class="content">')
                                .append('<div id="menu">')));
html.insertAfter('#primary');

$('#menu').append(menu(menu_contents)); 

function menu(m) {
    var ul = $('<ul>')

        $.each(m, function() {
            var li = $('<li>')
            li.append($('<a>', {text : this.title, href : this.href, id : this.id}));           
            ul.append(li)
            if(this.submenu) li.append(menu(this.submenu));
        })

    return ul;
}

$('ul li ul li').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
});

$(function() {
    var pageurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    $('#menu a').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('href') == pageurl || $(this).attr('href') == ''){
            $(this).addClass('menuOnselect');
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass('menuOffselect');
        }
    });
});

$('#ee').click(function() {
    $('#bb,#cc,#dd').css('display','none');
})});
```

Those code will create a simple menu：

```
    <div id="primary">
       <div id="secondary">
          <div class="block">
          <h1 id="h1" style="color:#ffffff;">Settings</h1>
             <div class="content">
                <div id="menu">
                   <ul>
                   <li><a href="a.html" class="menuOffselect">AA</a>
                      <ul>
                         <a href="b.html" id="bb" class="menuOffselect">BB</a>
                         <a href="c.html" id="cc" class="menuOffselect">CC</a>
                         <a href="d.html" id="dd" class="menuOffselect">DD</a>       
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="e.html" id="ee" class="menuOnselect">EE</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

And my question is... 
when I click one of menu items, like this one： 
`<li>
   <a href="ee.html" id="ee" class="menuOnselect">EE</a>
</li>`

it will direct to ee.html，but those code doesn't work：
`$('#ee').click(function() {
        $('#bb,#cc,#dd').css('display','none');
    })`

How to make .css() not only work when click menu items but also work after direct to the target page？can anybody help please？

Comment: @Alex I edited my question, thank you :-)

Comment: what r u trying to achieve?

Comment: My question is to make .css() not only work when click but also work after click menu items.

Comment: this is my full html：
<div id="primary"></div>
I use jQuery .append() to append html.

Comment: when page navigates all get reset. and one more thing the way you are binding your `click` event this might not work as you are creating your elements way after doc ready, so browser does not know that element exists in the dom.

Comment: @SC.Peng check my answer

Comment: Big thx for @Jai and @alex，I figure out something，thank you！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does work, the idea is flawed [Fiddle to your code](https://jsfiddle.net/rLbqz0Lj/)

What happens is, #bb,#cc,#dd get hidden, but then the page navigates away, which makes hiding them useless. You can see that the hiding actually happens when you add return false to the hiding function

```
$('#ee').click(function() {
    $('#bb,#cc,#dd').css('display','none');
    return false;//stop navigation
})
```

I guess what you want to do is to simply add

```
$('#bb,#cc,#dd').css('display','none');
```

To ee.html

Comment: After I add return false; it won't make #ee direct to the target url.

Comment: Yes, because as i said, the code works, the idea is just flawed because hiding elements before going to another url is meaningless. You need to hide them once you're there.

Comment: Ahhhh，I understood what you said，and your idea is work perfectly.
I want to seperate my menu from the original html page，but this idea is flawed，thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add your this code

```
$('#ee').click(function() {
$('#bb,#cc,#dd').css('display','none');
 })});
```

inside `$(document).ready(function(){...above code})`;